# configuration parameters for different module in xd instances

Tags: spring-xd

I have 3  spring  xd container running  and 1 admin server and 1 zookeeper with rabbit as transport.We  have s3 file puller which pull huge  file from s3 bucket .Now the issue is duplicate  records processed all container were pulling same files. Hence I had to make the module count as 1 instead of 3 .But It causes single point of failure.
So I wanted to try this approach like there will be s3 fill pull  source  module with  module count as 3  and each instance will pull fill from 3  different buckets in s3 like   b1 b2 b3  and i want to configure 3 difference instances of same source  to pull from 3 buckets ? Is this possible in xd?

Like my s3 source module in instance1 one to poll from b1
instance2 from b2
instance3 from b3

Answer (score 0):

The module instance number is not available as a property within a module. It might be possible with a custom plugin but it's probably simpler to just deploy 3 different streams.